# Global Search In Android

Tags: android

I want Messaging (Sms/Mms) application to be part of the global search i.e., when I type a word in the omni search box (on home screen), it should show me the messages which has that word.  Currently, we have local search within messaging app which works fine but how do I make messaging globally searchable.

I tried refereing searchable dictornary example and also some online resource but didn't help.  Please provide me the steps to make messaging application part of global search.

Regards,
Sunil.

Comment: I've read about doing this (somewhere, can't find it offhand), I believe it is possible. Never done it. Someone will be along to advise I am sure.

Answer (score 5):

Read the article provided here: <del>http://d.android.com/resources/articles/qsb.html</del>

It gives a proper step-by-step tutorial on how to set up a suggestion content provider and describe it in the application's Manifest. It's the de facto tutorial on how to do it. If you can't follow it through, there's not much we can do for you.

**Edit:** new links:

- http://developer.android.com/training/search/index.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html

Comment: @Hamid I have added new, undead, links.